# Options for converting/finding analogs for Java class libraries in C#?

Tags: c#, java, apache-axis, axiom, sharpen-tool

I've been tasked with rewriting a Java web services client in C#.NET. The only truly tedious part of this task has proven to be figuring out how to handle all the Java class libraries (sorry if that's not the right term--not nearly as experienced with Java as with C#). I'm looking at two different options:

1) decompiling the jars and using Sharpen to convert

2) decompiling or using online doc from Apache to just recreate the parts that I need

The biggest drawback to these two approaches is the question of whether there are any C# analogs to the Java classes that I'd be converting, which would mean that I'd be duplicating effort. The first option also has the drawback that some of the code might not convert cleanly, leaving it up to me to have to look through all the code to figure it out. The two most important libraries that I need C# equivalent code for are the Axis2 AxisFault and Constants libraries and the Axiom OM library.

**This is my question:** Are there any other options besides the two that I've listed? I've googled this a dozen times and all that I've found are those two options.

Comment: Are you required to rewrite the code to C#? Otherwise there are different Java-to-C# bridging solutions, for example [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/). There is also [ikvm.net](http://www.ikvm.net/) that allows you to translate Java bytecode to .NET IL.

Comment: Yes, the code must be C#. My boss is trying to make a clean break from Java. If it weren't for that I'd just add a GUI to the existing client and be done with it.